# Synchronise AD with TFS throws Error: TF20507

Tags: tfs, active-directory, tfs-2015

Synchronise AD with TFS 2015 worked properly for years even after the update from TFS 2013 to 2015. Suddenly the sync was broken. And the following Error came up:
[image: TF20507]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried to follow: [Mike Kaufmanns Blog](https://writeabout.net/2017/04/11/tfs-identity-synchronization-job-error/)
which will guide you to execute his program from [github](https://github.com/wulfland/FindInvalidCharsTool)
When executing this program a user popped up and his description had faulty characters.

We removed the whole Description and the Sync executed properly.

Regards

Comment: So the plan, but i have to wait another 3 hours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you add a group or user with illegal character to AD?

Like posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/62d286c2-ba0f-48e3-8cad-4da9e46d8cea/tfs20507-error-received-when-attempting-to-add-user-to-contributors-group-for-a-project?forum=tfsgeneral)

Team Foundation group accounts must not include non printable characters in the ASCII value range of 1-31. Tab's ASCII value is 9, so it's not supported in TFS.